# Is Rune-Etching as a Service a thing in Pathfinder 2e?

Tags: crafting, pathfinder-2e

I am currently preparing my first larger game after transitioning from Pathfinder 1e to 2e and stumbled upon the topic of runes.

The way I interpret the rules (specifically CRB page 580), it is assumed that PCs will no longer usually find specific magic weapons and armor along their adventure, instead they'll find runestones with magic runes that they can transfer onto their existing items themselves. However, as clarified in the section about the etching process, they need to meet the rune's crafting requirements (for +1 fundamental runes that means at least expert proficiency in Crafting and the Magical Crafting feat) to do so.

Is it be reasonable to assume that any party would at some point include at least one member who meets their etching requirements? If not (probably even if so), wouldn't it make sense for there to be people who agree to be paid for transfering a rune either from a runestone onto an item or between two items? What would be a reasonable rate for this service?

Comment: I opened a related question: [Does Transferring Runes have any specific requirements?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/174921/does-transferring-runes-have-any-specific-requirements); my 2e group's assumption has been that anyone with Crafting can transfer Runes if they can meet the DC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm currently running the Age of Ashes campaign, and there are a lot of magical weapons & armors in it (according to the rules of [Treasure by level](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=581)).

They could [transfer runes](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=736) according to the rules, on the weapons & armors they like (for example, transferring the [+1 potency rune](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=281) from a +1 sword to a scimitar to change it as a +1 scimitar).

I believe you could use the [earn income](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=560) rules to have someone doing this job for your players. I have, myself, used the size of the city to know what highest-level tasks were available, and use it to know the maximum level a rune might be.

For instance, my players were in a level 4 village and needed to transfer a [+1 potency rune](https://2e.aonprd.com/Equipment.aspx?ID=281) which is level 2. So they found a blacksmith for doing this, and I use the [earn income table 4-2](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=23) to set a price for the transfer. And they have also to pay the 10 % of the price of the rune for the transfer.

Comment: Fantastic idea! That makes perfect sense. Thanks a lot!